# Parse activity unstable, getting a few random results

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, urllib2

Here's the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('/users/Rachael/Desktop/CheckTitle.csv', 'r') as readcsv:
    for row in readcsv.readlines():
        try:
            openitem = urllib2.urlopen(row).read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(openitem, 'lxml')
            print soup.head.find('title').get_text()

        except urllib2.URLError:
            print 'passed'
            pass
```

I'm getting following results:

(a):

```
passed
贝贝网京外裁员10%：团队要保持狼性和危机感_新浪财经_新浪网
垂直电商贝贝网被曝裁员 回应称只是10%人员优化_新浪财经_新浪网
```

(b):

```
passed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Rachael/PycharmProjects/untitled1/GetTitle.py", line 10, in 
<module>
    print soup.head.find('title').get_text()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

(c):

```
passed
贝贝网京外裁员10%：团队要保持狼性和危机感_新浪财经_新浪网
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Rachael/PycharmProjects/untitled1/GetTitle.py", line 10, in <module>
    print soup.head.find('title').get_text()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

I'm getting these three types of results randomly.

If I do soup.title OR soup.title.text OR soup.title.string instead, it will return the same/similar error.

Please help!

I found this very hard to describe so if this is a dup in any ways please give me the link to similar posts.

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you sure those pages with errors have a `<head>` tag?

Comment: Yeah I checked the webpages they all have <head> tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'NoneType' object has no attribute` is an error that happens when there are no results for this object, try print only the `print soup.head.find('title')` title without printing the `.text` it should return something like '[]' or 'None'
***Answer***: There is no actual title **tag** or there's a **bot** protection of some kind on one of those sites you have in that file.